# MySQL 2 Columns from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

There we go actually I think it should be ok but it isn't

```
SELECT animize_users.username, animize_profile.avatar 
FROM animize_users, animize_profile 
WHERE `animize_profile.userid` = 1 AND `animize_users.id` = 1 
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

Please don't tell me to put this in a a seperate query each - as i don't want to make needless calls...

Comment: Care to share what the problem or error is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way with backticks correctly used:

```
SELECT animize_users.username, animize_profile.avatar 
FROM animize_users, animize_profile 
WHERE `animize_profile`.`userid` = 1 AND `animize_users`.`id` = 1 
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

Comment: @Jeff Watkins raises very valid points on the overall SQL, you should incorporate his observations.  I simply corrected where the problem was so that you could see what was actually the root of your grief.

Answer (score 3):

Just drop the quotes entirely if they're not required, i.e.

```
SELECT animize_users.username, animize_profile.avatar FROM animize_users au join animize_profile ap on ap.userid = au.id WHERE au.id = 1
```

If you've got a proper PK on user id, the user shouldn't repeat and really limit 1 would only effect your selection of profile. I'd suggest adding to the where to ensure you get the most appropriate profile.

Also, if "animize" is your product, don't prefix your tables with it, it's redundant.

Comment: I like this one, no really - as I am quite experienced with SQL, but never had to write complex queries myself, I thought about using join but in the explaination of a friend the above way was shown and I thought way not :)! Unfortunally it's to late to give you the "right answer", and Greg was faster as well, but anyways thanks for taking your time :).

Comment: @IvanSchrecklich No problems, I'm just glad I could help :)